# Problem with the number of links in a new directory in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, directory, ls, mkdir, ln

I have create a new `directory` in `ubuntu terminal` on `VirtualBox` and with the command `ls -ldi` i saw that the number of `links`is two even if the directory is empty. Can someone explain me why? This is an example:

`riccardo@riccardo-Virtualbox:~$mkdir newDir
riccardo@riccardo-Virtualbox:~$ls -ldi newDir
1576810 drwxr-xr-x 2 riccardo riccardo 4096 apr 17 16:12 newDir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of links is 2 because the directory is linked to:

`.`

`..`

Comment: Thanks! I saw this better using the command `ls -a newDir` refered to the example used in the question